# Improve Tree Node Graph

Tags: tikz-trees

Can you help improve the diagram? The distance J's and P's are not equal. In addition, the graph is too wide. I want it to be more narrow so it fits in A5 paper or so.

My code is

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={
            treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=3pt, 
                text centered, font=\sffamily},
            arn_n/.style = {treenode, rectangle, text width=3em},
            arn_x/.style = {treenode},
            gray-arrow/.style = {draw=gray}}
        [MBTI, arn_n
        [E, arn_n
        [S, arn_n
        [T, arn_n
        [J, arn_x]
        [P, arn_n]]
        [F, arn_n
        [J, arn_n]
        [P, arn_n]]]
        [N, arn_n
        [T, arn_n
        [J, arn_x]
        [P, arn_n]]
        [F, arn_n
        [J, arn_n]
        [P, arn_n]      ]]]
        [I, arn_n
        [S, arn_n
        [T, arn_n
        [J, arn_x]
        [P, arn_n]]
        [F, arn_n
        [J, arn_n]
        [P, arn_n]]]
        [N, arn_n
        [T, arn_n
        [J, arn_x]
        [P, arn_n]]
        [F, arn_n
        [J, arn_n]
        [P, arn_n]]]]]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
          [MBTI [E [S [T [J] [P]] [F [J] [P]] ] [N [T [J] [P]] [F [J]
                  [P] ]]] [I [S [T [J] [P]] [F [J] [P]]] [N [T [J]
                  [P]] [F [J] [P]]]]]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One more thing I forget about which is can I have the sum of all letter under J's and P's like 
E
S
T
J